# If I have that $L(v)=L(w)$ for all $L \in V^*$, can I conclude that $v=w$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be a finite dimensional vector space. If I have that $L(v)=L(w)$ for all $L \in V^*$(where $V^*$ is the dual space of V), can I conclude that $v=w$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assume that $v\neq w$. 
 If we choose a basis $\{e_i\}$ for $V$ then we have $$ v=\sum a_i e_i,\ w=\sum b_ie_i$$

By assumption we have $i$ s.t. $a_i\neq b_i$

Define $L $ s.t. $$ L(e_i)=1,\ L(e_j)=0\ (i\neq j) $$

Then $L(v)\neq L(w)$ It is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In fact, by linearity, it suffices to check that $L_a(v) = L_a(w)$ for all $L_a$ is some basis of $V^*$.

An easy way to prove this would be as follows: It's obvious if $v = 0$, and if $v$ is not zero, we can extend it a basis $(v, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$ of $V$, and prove it in the dual basis.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $b_1,...,b_n$ so that $b_k$ form a basis for $V$.
Define $L_k \in V^*$ by $L_k(b_i) = \delta_{ik}$, then if $L_k (x) = 0$ for all $k$, we have $x = 0$ (since any $x$ can be written as $x = \sum_k x_k b_k$).

Let $x=v-w$ to get the desired result.